# application server integration into development process

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly

Aloha,

I am currently doing my Master thesis in writing an internal Web Application. I'm pretty much starting from scratch. Of course there are some requirements but those are not too important for my question.

Giving the case that there will be further development/maintenance when I'm finished with the thesis from 4-6 developers.

What I've done in previous projects/assignments was installing the Application Server (AS) by hand (setting it up etc.) on my developer machine.

What I've done as well is to use Maven to install and configure something like Jetty/Tomcat and the other developers just have to get the Maven project, run mvn install and their good to go.

But what will you do with an AS like Wildfly?

**My Question would be is there any best practice for handling an AS in a team from 4-6 developers?** (AS just on developer machines, not Devevelopment/Quality/Production systems)

Comment: You could include the configuration file(s) in your vcs - then it is just about installing wildfly and copying/pasting the config file(s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 4 options if you considering the Wildfly as your AS

1. Include your modified `standalone.xml` inside your project, maybe in `src/main/resources/` folder, every developer can pull it through Git or whatever VCS are you using.
2. You can create [CLI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/CLI+Recipes) script for a Wildfly and include it to your code base again. You can find some tutorial on the internet, for instance [here](http://www.tecmint.com/wildfly-jboss-as-how-to-access-and-manage-cli-using-gui/). The advantage over XML is that you don't have to modify source manually, script can be executed as a batch which means it will either configure everything correctly or leave it intact.
3. Configure Wildfly through the [Maven plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/execute-commands-mojo.html). You can run there same commands as in option 2, some example can be seen [here](https://docs.jboss.org/wildfly/plugins/maven/latest/examples/execute-commands-example.html).
4. You can also upload a modified ZIP with your server to some location and make every developer use this version. Downside is that everybody will have to download this ZIP again if you make any modifications to the configuration.

So I think option number 3 is the best (because it's most automated and it's easiest to spread the configuration change among all developers) however your `pom.xml` can get really bloated with configuration. In this case, you can combine it with option number 2 so the Maven plugin will just ran the CLI script file from inside of your project.

Comment: What's wrong with preparing one server, zipping it up and spreading it around to the other development machines? Its a one-time installation thing.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, I just think that executing a simple command from console (running CLI script) is better than messing up with files on the server on editing XML manually if something goes wrong. Also you automate it more easily (like I said, one command).

Comment: Ah sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you are talking about spreading `standalone.xml` or other configs. Of course this can be right option but I still think that spreading few kilobytes of text is better than 120 MG file :)

Comment: Hello, we're living in the 21st century where downloading 120mb from the internet is a matter of seconds ;) Its just so easy to park such a thing on an FTP or network drive somewhere (which is what I do in any case).

Comment: Sure, but I still consider faster typing `git pull` and `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --file=config.cli`. You don't have to ZIP anything, upload it somewhere and make everybody replace their server with whatever own settings they have (I would be really pissed of as a developer in this case).

Comment: Cheers Petr, I'll probably gonna go with option 3 as I was thinking about that myself. Cheers for the comments as well.